# How can i prevent timer skips my asp.net online exam project when multiples user login at a time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is that I'm using a timer in my asp.net online exam website.
One user logins to attempt to test my timer reducing the time value work as expected but multiple users attempted to the test that time my timer has skipping the ticks and its goes very fast. I don't know what the reason is

My code.cs is

```
protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (TimeAllSecondes > 0)
    {
        TimeAllSecondes = TimeAllSecondes - 1;
        if (TimeAllSecondes < 0)
        {
            Session["endtime"] = DateTime.Now;
            //Session["SubjectID3"] = txtsubid.Value;
            //Session["SubjectName3"] = txtsubname.Value;
            mcqmethod.update_astatus(Convert.ToString(Session["empid"]), Convert.ToInt32(Session["EXAMID"]));
            Response.Redirect("~/MCQ/students/s_thankyou.aspx");

        }
    }

    TimeSpan time_Span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeAllSecondes);
    hh = time_Span.Hours;
    mm = time_Span.Minutes;
    ss = time_Span.Seconds;
    lblTimer.Text = " Your exam time is remaining :  " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss + "[H:M:S]";
}

<asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick" ></asp:Timer>
```

This is the method define

```
static double TimeAllSecondes;

public void getexam()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = mcqmethod.getexambysub(Convert.ToInt32(Session["EXAMID"]),Convert.ToString(Session["empid"]));
    lblsubject.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["subname"]);
    lbltime.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["etime"]);
    noofquestion = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["t_n_q"]);
    Session["ExamDate"] = dt.Rows[0]["e_date"];
    Session["examtime"] = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["etime"]);//Minutes of exam
    DateTime examdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["ExamDate"]);//date of exam
    DateTime  endexam = examdate.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(Session["examtime"]));

    Session["starttime"] = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan remingtime = endexam.Subtract(DateTime.Now);       
    TimeAllSecondes = remingtime.TotalSeconds;         
    Session["noq"] = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[0]["t_n_q"]);
    btnprev.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm immediately suspicious of `TimeAllSecondes`. But you haven't shown us where it's defined.

Comment: Ok sure i will show that one

Comment: DateTime examdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["ExamDate"]);//date of exam
            DateTime  endexam = examdate.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(Session["examtime"]));

            Session["starttime"] = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan remingtime = endexam.Subtract(DateTime.Now);       
            TimeAllSecondes = remingtime.TotalSeconds;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use static fields inside an asp.net application for something that is *user specific* since they're shared across all users.<sup>1</sup>

Likewise, you cannot use instance fields since page instances only last the lifetime of a single request/response lifecycle.

What you want is something that is isolated to a single user and has a lifetime length the same as the time the user spends on your site.

That's [ASP.Net Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx), and that's where you should store your `TimeAllSecondes` value.

---

<sup>1</sup>This glosses over lots of instances where they will appear to lose their state also, such as when an application pool recycles or when you're running multiple instances of your process. But in short, they don't have the *right* isolation and lifetime semantics.

Comment: i am not storing the value any where first i get the all the seconds and i put a timer every sec limit then its automatically ticks every seconds..

Comment: @user3296718 - you need to store it, and you need to store it *in the session*, just like `empid` and anything else you want to be *isolated* from other users and have an extended lifetime.

Comment: @user3296718 - and the reason you get "skips" is that for four users, there are four timers running each second and they're all running the same logic against that same variable, so it's going down by four each second (approximately)

Comment: Thank you so much ..i have tried what and all you told i got the result now timer is working fine with multiple users